# DC/DC step down timer

Tags: voltage-regulator, timer

I need simple circuit that can provide step down of voltage after some time. For example after connecting 24V, on output there will be 24V for 500msec, after that voltage will step down to 8V and stay there. After each power on, the circuit will repeat this.

What is simple way to do this? (not using any controller etc.)

Comment: the simple way is using some controller ect.

Comment: what kind of controller would you recoomend ?

Comment: A time relay connected to switch between 24V and 8V or classic relay with RC delay.

Comment: You can use a monostable multivibrator.

Comment: If you [edit] to explain the real application you will eliminate a lot of guessing and get much better answers.

Comment: How accurate must the 500ms be? Please edit the question with this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R3 will be in parallel to R1 after a certain delay which is fixed by R6 and C6.

Diode D6 will discharge C6 to the load ad power-off.

At power-up C6 will be a short circuit and will keep Q2 off.

At power-up R4 will keep Q1 off.

In the picture, R1 and R2 have dummy values.

---

To complete the design one has to set the values of:  R1,R2, R3, R6, C6

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to simulate this circuit to see output when i change values ?

Comment: Yes, download LT Spice. LT Spice doesn't have the LM2596 part. Use another DC/DC buck converter, they are all equal. LTSpice comes with many DC/DC buck converters macro models.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a hardware interview question. Basically "can you build a timer without a clock". The simplicity of the answer would surprise you.

[image]

The current source can be built from a simple current mirror, and you can choose your C according to the equation. Furthermore you can follow the output by a CMOS inverter to get a more defined edge at the end of the timer. Just keep in mind if you use the inverter now you'll need 2*t instead of just t.

I would draw you a schematic for it, but as a hobbyist or student where's the fun for you on that? :)

Answer (score 0):

It actually sounds a lot like a solenoid driver. You push with 24,then go down to lower voltage to keep it in place and not overheat it. One solution is actually to use an 8V input and a boost converter with a limited current. Then when solenoid is activated, it gets the 24 for a short time, discharges the capacitor and remains at iV (minus the diode).